# Is there a way to ensure subplot tick labels use a fixed amout of space?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When making subplots in matplotlib, the spines typically line up. However, I have plots with orders of magnitude difference which causes the tick labels to use different widths. Consequently, the axes labels do not line up.

Ideally, the width of each tick label take up could be automatically set to the maximum width required by any subplot. Is there a way to do this?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

n = 10
x = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
y = np.zeros((n, 4))
y[:, 0] = 1
y[:, 1] = 1e6
y[:, 2] = 1000 * x
y[:, 3] = (x / 100) ** 4

labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

spec = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, wspace=0.45)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = np.empty((2, 2), dtype=object)
i = 0
for r in range(2):
    for c in range(2):
        ax[r, c] = fig.add_subplot(spec[r, c])
        ax[r, c].plot(x, y[:, i])
        ax[r, c].set_ylabel(labels[i])
        i += 1

# Draw box around column 1 labels
fig.patches.extend([plt.Rectangle((0.025, 0.25 / 2), 0.03, 0.75,
                                  fill=True, color='g', alpha=0.5, zorder=1000,
                                  transform=fig.transFigure, figure=fig)])

# Draw box around column 2 labels
fig.patches.extend([plt.Rectangle((0.495, 0.25 / 2), 0.03, 0.75,
                                  fill=True, color='g', alpha=0.5, zorder=1000,
                                  transform=fig.transFigure, figure=fig)])
plt.show()
```

The green boxes help illustrate the alignment of the y labels. Notice the labels are not aligned due to the different ytick label widths.

[image: misaligned labels]

Comment: `ax.align_ylabels`: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.align_ylabels